# How do I have to add a Manufacturers in Magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes

How do I have to add the **Manufacturers Attribute** in Magento using php?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean?  "Manufacturers" is the name of an existing attribute? you need to assign a value for this attribute to a product?  You need to create the attribute programatically?

Comment: -1 hazy question : a word is missing in the title, the question paraphrases the title... and you're using 'the' as though the manufacturers attribute was a design pattern. Plus, I think you're question just is "How do I programmatically add an attribute to a product model?". This answer can be found by searching google.

Comment: I have already solved it! Thanks guys

Answer (score -2):

```
private function addManufacturers($manufacturer){

        //add new manufacturer
        $option['attribute_id'] = 70; //manufacturer
        $option['value']['any_key_that_resolves_to_zero'][0] = $manufacturer;

        $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
        $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
        return $this->getManufacturerId($manufacturer);

}
```